# How to get the size of the actual image frame inside UIImagePicker on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am implementing a kind of "augmented reality" app which has to add guide to the user on the image being taken. In order to do this `camerOverlayView` is used. The problem is that I have to place the guide on the image too. For that I need the size and the position of actual image on the `UIImagePickerController`. Where can it be found from?
[image]

Comment: In your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` the actual image size is available as `[[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] size]`  Not sure if that's really where you're looking for it though.

Comment: @David, you are right, I need it before the picture is taken.

Comment: I am facing the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Seems that nobody knows how to handle it, and they all give the same useless reference...

Comment: There is no real solution here. I had to hard-code the resolution into the application.

Answer (score -1):

For iPhone 4: 5.0 MP (2592 x 1936) - Frame : (0.0, 0.0, 2592.0, 1936.0)

For iPhone 5: 8.0 MP (3264 x 2448) - Frame : (0.0, 0.0, 3264.0, 2448.0)

Comment: Although, technically correct, this makes me hard code this, which is undesirable. Take into an account that width of the frame is standard 480 and not 2592/3264, while the height might be calculated using 4:3 aspect ratio. The question is whether I can detect this from the view itself?